# SSIS - Why do I need "project connection manager" instead of "project parameters"?

Tags: ssis

I'm creating SQL Server Integration Services 2014 project in project deployment model.

For example, I'm connecting to a database and I want this connection to be centralized within the project scope.

My question, why do I need **project connection manager**? I like **project parameter**, as far as I know they do similar job as project connection managers + additional things e.g. they bind with SSDT Configuration Manager so I can have dev/QA configuration etc…

Under what circumstances will I need **project connection manager** instead of **project parameter**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A project connection manager ensures that all the consumers of that resource use a consistent value. Using project level parameters to specify user name, server, etc, allows all the packages to have *access* to the correct value but there is **no** guarantee that all packages will consistently apply the correct pattern of expressions to get the configuration managers properly configured for an environment. Simply stated, the project level connection managers remove the opportunity for mistake.

Once deployed to the SSIDB, you can use Configurations there to ensure your projects are using the correct resource. It can be an all/some/none approach to configure your project level entities: connection managers and parameters.